# Getting the hashed password from ASP.NET Membership Provider

Tags: passwords, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Is there any method on the MembershipProvider (or the Membership instance) which I can use to get the hashed password itself? I'm not trying to do a recovery, I'm not trying to find the actual password, I just need the hashed string.

Also, while I'm at it, can I get the exact algorithm's name (like SHA1 or MD5) used to create that hash?

Answer (score 0):

No, I couldn't find any method that returns HashedPassword. Even if you get HashedPassword, you still need salt.

Default hash algorithm is salted base64 `SHA1`.

```
public string EncodePassword(string pass, string saltBase64) 
{ 
   byte[] bytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(pass); 
   byte[] src = Convert.FromBase64String(saltBase64); 
   byte[] dst = new byte[src.Length + bytes.Length]; 
   Buffer.BlockCopy(src, 0, dst, 0, src.Length); 
   Buffer.BlockCopy(bytes, 0, dst, src.Length, bytes.Length); 
   HashAlgorithm algorithm = HashAlgorithm.Create("SHA1"); 
   byte[] inArray = algorithm.ComputeHash(dst); 
   return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray); 
}
```